# Are the training loss and validation loss plotted per sample or per batch?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, objective-functions, supervised-learning, pytorch

I am using a CNN to train on some data, where training size = 21700 samples, and test size is 653 samples, and say I am using a batch_size of 500 (I am accounting for samples out of batch size as well).

I have been looking this up for a long time now, but can't get a clear answer, but when plotting the loss functions to check for whether the model is overfitting or not, do I plot as follows

```
for j in range(num_epochs):
  <some training code---Take gradient descent step do wonders>
  batch_loss=0
  for i in range(num_batches_train):
       batch_loss = something....criterion(target,output)...
       total_loss += batch_loss
  Losses_Train_Per_Epoch.append(total_loss/num_samples_train)#and this is
```

where I need help

```
Losses_Train_Per_Epoch.append(total_loss/num_batches_train)
and doing the same for Losses_Validation_Per_Epoch.
plt.plot(Losses_Train_Per_Epoch, Losses_Validation_Per_epoch)
```

So, basically, what I am asking is, should I divide by num_samples or num_batches or batch_size? Which one is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to compute the **mean** loss over all batches. What you need to do is to divide the sum of batch losses with the number of batches!

#### In your case:

You have a training set of $21700$ samples and a batch size of $500$. This means that you take $21700/500 \approx 43$ training iterations. This means that for each epoch the model is updated $43$ times! So the way you compute your training loss, that is what you need to divide by.

Note: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to plot but I'm assuming you want to plot the training losses and the validation losses

```
training_loss = []
validation_loss = []
training_steps = num_samples // batch_size
validation_steps = num_validation_samples // batch_size

for epoch in range(num_epochs):

    # Training steps
    total_loss = 0
    for b in range(training_steps):
        batch_loss = ...  # compute batch loss
        total_loss += batch_loss
    training_loss.append(total_loss / training_steps)

    # Validation steps
    total_loss = 0
    for b in range(validation_steps):
        batch_loss = ...  # compute batch validation loss
        total_loss += batch_loss
    training_loss.append(total_loss / validation_steps)

# Plot training and validation curves
plt.plot(range(num_epochs), training_loss)
plt.plot(range(num_epochs), validation_loss)
```

Another way would be to store the losses in a list and compute the mean. You can use this if you're not sure with what to divide.

```
...

for epoch in range(num_epochs):

    list_of_batch_losses = []  # initialize list that is going to store batch losses

    # Training steps
    for b in range(training_steps):
        batch_loss = ...  # compute batch loss
        list_of_batch_losses.append(batch_loss)  # store loss in a list

    epoch_loss = np.mean(list_of_batch_losses)
    training_loss.append(epoch_loss)

    ...

plt.plot(range(num_epochs), training_loss)
```

Comment: Yup! I wanted to print the training and validation losses. Earlier, i was dividing by number of samples for training and validation respectively, and i they had very different scales, so my training loss looked much much greater than my validation loss. But yeah, what you said is right and worked for me. Thank you :-) .